# Parsing ATOM feed in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, xml, dojo, atom-feed

I am trying to parse an ATOM feed and display the relevant parts I need. After doing some searching, I couldn't find a way to do this in Dojo, so I wrote this implementation to get by in the meantime (var xml contains the atom feed):

```
var names = this.getArray(xml.getElementsByTagName("name"));
var contents = this.getArray(xml.getElementsByTagName("content"));
var emails = this.getArray(xml.getElementsByTagName("email"));
var pubTimes = this.getArray(xml.getElementsByTagName("published"));

getArray: function(data) {
    var theArray = [];
    dojo.forEach(data, function (entry) {
        theArray.push(entry);
    });
    return theArray;
}
```

These arrays are then used to print out a formatted version of the ATOM feed. I'm new to Javascript and Dojo, and I'm sure there is a better/easier way to parse the XML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [dojox.atom](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/atom)?

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old post but I thought I'd add an answer in case someone stumbles across it as I just did.*

I do the following when I have an atom feed:

```
// Build xml feed from a document element (in this case `xml`)
var feed = new dojox.atom.io.model.Feed();
feed.buildFromDom(xml);

// Convert to json
var jsonString = dojo.toJson(feed, true);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString );
```

Then I can easily use `jsonObj.*key*` to get or set the data.